# Calculating pairs in python dask

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, dask, delay

I'm trying to calculate all possible combinations of pairs starting from 0 to the length of my file (62977) so i get this result as a single dask series\data frame with no duplicates:

(0,1), (0,2), (0,3) ... (1,2), (1,2), ... (62975,62976)

This is what I tried in dask but it takes a very long time and leads to Memory error:

```
def generate_combinations_with_first_value(start, end):
    combinations_list = []
    for j in range(start, end):
        if j != start:
            combinations_list.append((start, j))
    return combinations_list


# Function to compute pairs with the same first value in parallel
def compute_pairs_with_same_first_value(end_range):
    combinations_list = [(start, end_range) for start in range(end_range - 1)]
    combinations = dd.from_pandas(pd.Series(combinations_list), npartitions=partitions)
    combinations_bag = combinations.map(lambda args: generate_combinations_with_first_value(*args),
                                        meta=pd.Series([], dtype='float64'))
    return combinations_bag


 if __name__ == '__main__':
combinations_array = compute_pairs_with_same_first_value(file_len)
combinations_df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'pairs': combinations_array}), npartitions=1).explode(
    'pairs').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in dask?

Thank you!

Comment: At one point, you are computing combinations_array, in order to feed it into a Pandas DataFrame. This list (if my math are correct : n(n-1)/2 formula) has almost 2 billions pairs of float64 (why float64 ??) values, which means about 28GiB.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB Yes, how can I improve this?